# How to plot a CSV file containing labels and their counts in R?

Tags: r, csv, plot, graph

R newbie here, so you're probably going to judge but here's my question.

I have a very simple structured CSV file that has 2 columns: labels (ASCII text values) as column 1 and their respective counts (numerical) as column 2.

For example, the CSV is of the format:

```
type,count
cat,23000
dog,444566,
wolf,3442
tiger,306
...
```

I want to plot a simple line graph in R that has 'counts' as y-axis and labels on x-axis. I wish to actually be able to see the 'labels' such as 'dog' 'cat' marked on the x-axis or data-point. How do I do this in R?

Here's what I have so far:

```
> heresmydata <- read.csv("data.csv")
> matplot(heresmydata[, 1], heresmydata[, -1], type="l")
Warning messages:
1: In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log = log) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
2: In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : NAs introduced by coercion
>
```

It produces an empty graph with improper labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `ggplot2`

```
library("ggplot2")
ggplot(heresmydata, aes(x = type, y = count)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_y_log10()
```

Comment: That "works" but the result is highly illegible. It seems to be a bar graph (instead of a line graph) and no 'text labels' pertaining to x values. For clarity, some y values are very low such as 200, while other might be very high (in millions). Also, I have a total of 1000 rows in the CSV

Comment: If you really want a line graph, use geom_line instead of geom_bar. With data spanning several orders of magnitude, you will need to log the axis - see edit

Comment: Awesome. Some 'x-labels', or ASCII text values in the X-axis, are being over-written into each other. Any way to 'tilt' them or something to ensure they don't overwrite each other (I have selected a subset such that there are only 20 X-labels being plotted now)?

Comment: Fixed it by adding this: `+ theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1,vjust=0.5)`

Answer (score 2):

Roughed out in base R graphics.  Look at `axis`, `mtext` and `plot` options to refine.

Read in: `data <- read.csv("data.csv", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`

Plot: `plot(data$count, type="l", axes=FALSE, ylim=c(min(data$count), max(data$count)), xlab="Creature", ylab="Count")`

Y axis:`axis(side=2, at=c(min(data$count), max(data$count)), labels=c(min(data$count), max(data$count)))`

X axis: `axis(side=1, at=seq(1,nrow(data),1), labels=data$type)`

Comment: Add `las=2` to X axis command to display text vertically and increase legibility. Its size can be altered with `cex=.5` within the same command.

Comment: That does plot the line graph, however, the x-label is not displaying the actual ASCII text such as 'cat' 'dog' etc. but is listing numbers such as '1' '2' etc. Any way to fix that?

Comment: In the `plot` call, `axes=FALSE` should suppress numeric labels initially.  Then in `axis(side=1...`, as long as `data$type` is of type `chr`, you should get the text plotted.  Was R returning any warnings or errors on either the `plot` or `axis` calls?